# I want my content to be pushed down when the menu slider down

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, push

I want my web content to be pushed down when i click my "menu" button and the menu slides down, I have tried making the content position relative with no defined height but it's still not working.

My menu is wrapped under a  ...  tag and has the CSS :

```
#wrapper {margin: 0px auto 0; width: 800px; }
```

My content is wrapped under a  ...  tag and the CSS :

```
.container {
width: 100%;
position: relative;
}
```

I am using jquery for the menu and this is the document ready action :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var menu = $('#menu')
$('#menu-trigger').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if (menu.is(":visible"))
    {
        menu.slideUp(400);
        $(this).removeClass("open");
    }
    else
    {
        menu.slideDown(400);
        $(this).addClass("open");
    }
}); });
```

Comment: make a fiddle showing your problem

Comment: What does the 'open' class do ?

Comment: your HTML ? provide a jsfiddle

Comment: @rex http://jsfiddle.net/5j9zC/

Comment: @CodingAnt http://jsfiddle.net/5j9zC/

Comment: @Jundev here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5j9zC/ and the open class does almost the same thing as a .slideToggle , "opens" my menu

Comment: @Alin when menu comes down you want the rest of the content to go down with the same height??

Comment: @rex yes, I want my content to slide down with the same height. Anyhow the height is irrelevant cause I will be able to change that later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a 'push' class to bring the container down, and remove it when the menu is collapsed.

```
if (menu.is(":visible"))
    {
        menu.slideUp(400,  function() {
        $(this).removeClass("open");
        $('.container').removeClass("push");           
        });         
    }
    else
    {
        menu.slideDown(400, function() {
        $(this).addClass("open");
        $('.container').addClass("push");            
        });

    }

.push {    
    bottom: -150px !important;
}
```

Not the best approach. But I hope it does the job for you.

Here is the [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/5j9zC/3/). Hope it helps.

**Update**

You could try adding jquery animation to make it look smoother.

```
    if (menu.is(":visible"))
    {
        menu.slideUp(400,  function() {
        $(this).removeClass("open");
        $( ".container" ).animate({
         bottom: "+=50",    
        }, 1000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
        });              
        });         
    }
    else
    {
        menu.slideDown(400, function() {
        $(this).addClass("open");
        $( ".container" ).animate({
        bottom: "-=50",    
        }, 1000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
       });     

        });

    }
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5j9zC/5/)

Another approach would be to dynamically add a div between the container and the menu using jquery, set it a height and slide it down when the menu is open, and collapse it when the menu is closed. You would effectively do this in the callback part of your existing slideDown function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, it is not the cleanest approach since it doesn't quite use jquery for smooth sliding the "push" down...It simply drops it 150px lower.

Comment: Thank you, it's working fine like this, not quite the effect i was hoping for but anyhow...i still can't understand why my container won't go down by itself with the height of the menu when triggered since it's position is relative and with no predefined height...I'm too go over all my script and figure it out, for now your update will do. Thank you for the quick answer. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit rectification of CSS & HTML , you can achieve what you required,
no need to modify your js .

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/codingantGit/33W5v/

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">

#wrapper{margin: 0px auto 0; width: 800px; }

.container {
width: 100%;
position: relative;

}

.frame {
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-left:0;
  padding: 10px;
  height:30px;
  width: 100%;
  /*border-bottom: 1px solid #666;*/
}
#header {
  float: left;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100$;
  margin-left:-10px;

}

#menu-trigger {
  float: left;
  font-family: Baskerville, "Baskerville Old Face", "Hoefler Text", Garamond, "Times New Roman", serif;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  position: relative;
  color: #151515;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s linear;
  transition: color 0.2s linear;
}

#menu-trigger:hover {
  color: #888888;
}
#menu-trigger span.arrow {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: -15px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: url(../images/menu-arrow_sprite.png) no-repeat;
}
#menu-trigger.open span.arrow {
  background-position: 0 -12px;
}

#menu {
 background: url("../images/trans-black_50.png") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    display: none;
    height: 120px !important;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 4%;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 800px;
    z-index: 1000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
  border-top: 1px solid #666;
}
#menu .column {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 240px;
}
#menu .column:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
#menu .column h3 {
  border: none;
  color: #066666;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}
#menu .column ul {
  font-size: .75em;
  list-style: none;
}
#menu .column ul:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
#menu .column ul li {
  /*border-bottom: 1px solid #666;*/
}
#menu .column ul li:first-child {
 /* border-top: 1px solid #666;*/
}
#menu .column ul li a {
  color: #666;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: padding-left .5s;
  -moz-transition: padding-left .5s;
  -ms-transition: padding-left .5s;
  -webkit-transition: padding-left .5s;
  -o-transition: padding-left .5s;
}
#menu .column ul li a:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.main {
/*  padding-bottom: 80px;*/
}
.mi-slider {
  position: relative;
  margin-top:0px;
/*  min-height: 490px;*/
}

.mi-slider ul {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
    /*text-align: center;*/
    width: 100%;
}

</style>
```

HTML

```
 <div id="wrapper">
  <div class="frame">
    <div id="header">       
      <a href="#" id="menu-trigger">Meniu<span class="arrow"></span></a>
        <div id="menu">
            <div class="column">
                <h3>Navigare</h3>
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="index.html">Prima pagina</a></li>
                  <li><a href="colectie-apa.html">Colectie Apa</a></li>
                  <li><a href="colectie-fum.html">Colectie Fum</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.column-->
        </div>


    <div class="container"> 
      <div class="main">
        <div id="mi-slider" class="mi-slider">
          <ul>
            <li><h4>Colibri</h4></a></li>
            <li><h4>Maci</h4></a></li>
            <li><h4>Cameleon</h4></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- /container -->
```